# Выпадающий список для андроид/айфон

Tags: меню, android, javascript

Вот есть сайт booking.com, у него есть выбор языка (вверху справа), если зайти на сайт с устройств айфон, андроид и клацнуть по выбору языка, то откроется список на весь экран такой, как если бы мы нажали на select. Как можно самому сделать такое меню?

Смотрел код сайта, но не смог разобраться в нем, возможно уже есть готовые примеры.

Comment: Извините за оффтоп, но вас не смущает написание "андроид/айфон"? Это ведь всё-равно что написать "виндовс/асус"

Comment: @Crasher нет, не смущает. Можно, кстати, если чуть чуть подумать головой, понять, что имел ввиду автор: ios и android. Приведите пример сайта. А по сути: делаем евент на какой-то элемент, который активирует другой элемент, закрывающий собой весь сайт с position: fixed;

Comment: Если бы автор подумал еще больше головой, то и сказал бы что требуется реализация выпадающего списка для сайта, а не для аппы - две большие разницы между прочим.